# Does an Android Market test account actually get charged by In-App purchase?

Tags: android, google-play

I've followed the steps to upload the [In-App Billing Sample App](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) as an unpublished, draft app on the Market for testing purposes. I have my google account set up as a [Test Account](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-testing-setup) under my Market credentials and was wondering if my credit card will actually be charged when I purchase the potion or sword?

I know that I should refund the purchase from my Google Checkout Merchant account but will it actually charge my card if I don't?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Okay, after actually trying it, my card is really charged. Just an fyi for anybody that was wondering. The four android.test.xxx product IDs are the only test transactions that are possible that won't use your real account info and card.

Comment: I wish android could officially provide some support in this regard. Thanks anyways!!